# Sending DateTimeOffset from Android to .NET Web API

Tags: java, android, gson, azure-mobile-services, datetimeoffset

I am using Azure Mobile Apps SDK for Android.

```
public class MyClass {
    public String Id;
    public String Code;
    public DateTimeOffset ClientCreatedAt;
}

MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
myClass.Id = "1234567890";
myClass.Code = "dfgdrvyet";
myClass.ClientCreatedAt = new DateTimeOffset(new Date());
```

It is being used as follows:

```
MobileServiceSyncTable<MyClass> myClassSyncTable = _client.getSyncTable(MyClass.class);
ListenableFuture<MyClass> responseFuture = myClassSyncTable.insert(myClass);
```

Upon insertion, the `ClientCreatedAt` is set to null, when I investigated the insert statement, it is the Gson within the library that is not serialising the DatetimeOffset, specifically, this line:

```
JsonObject json = mClient.getGsonBuilder().create().toJsonTree(item).getAsJsonObject();
```

When I replace the `DateTimeOffset` with `Date`, the value is serialised properly.

So, my questions are:

1. Is it intended in Azure Mobile Apps for me to use the DateTimeOffset and if so, what is the right way to use it?
2. Can I force Gson to serialise the DateTimeOffset properly? I looked at the Gson Annotations, but nothing that can help there. I am not sure if I should be creating a getter and a setter for serialising and deserialising.

Answer (score 2):

`DateTimeOffset` is actually a dumb wrapper of `Date`.  Here it is in its entirety.

```
/**
 * Represents a point in time, typically expressed as a date and time of day
 */
public class DateTimeOffset extends Date {

    public DateTimeOffset(Date date) {
        this.setTime(date.getTime());
    }
}
```

I threw my hands up in the air and simply decided to use Strings instead, and joda-time's DateTime class via `DateTime.parse(string)` to handle them.

However the nice alternative is probably to register your own serialiser via `MobileServiceClient.registerSerializer(...)` but you won't get anything useful out of using their wrapper.

This SDK is rubbish.

edit: Using a custom (de)serialiser seems to work quite well:

```
private class DateTimeSerialiser implements JsonSerializer<DateTime>, JsonDeserializer<DateTime> {
    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(final DateTime src, final Type typeOfSrc, final JsonSerializationContext context) {
        return new JsonPrimitive(src.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public DateTime deserialize(final JsonElement json, final Type typeOfT, final JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        return DateTime.parse(json.getAsString());
    }
}
```

Set it up to deserialise/serialise to/from the object of your choice, then set an instance of it via `MobileServiceClient.registerSerializer + registerDeserializer`.  If using local sync, just use `ColumnDataType.String` or `ColumnDataType.DateTimeOffset` (it's just String under the hood). Now you can have your field set to the type you want.

```
private DateTime date;
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's not to late for answer. I have same issue. You can use
`Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
    String formattedDate = df.format(c.getTime());`
to parse date. IMHO would be easier to use Gson and Volley. I think you can read it as string and then convert it to Date.

Comment: Is this regarding the DateTimeOffset Azure SDK class?

Comment: I mean use string in class, but insert date in this format type. Something like this 
` public class MyClass{
  public String Id;
  public String ClientCreatedAt;
}

MyClass inst = new MyClass();
inst.ClientCreatedAt = df.Format(c.getTime);`